# UI dynamic nested modal

Tags: nested-tables

I am doing a complex nested display and data entry. So here how it goes. User will select an indicator and input a program,project and activity, however it can be either of the 3, or 2 of those or only 1 of it. Then they will add accounts or select accounts. It can be  account to a programs or project or activities and they will choose a fund source too and the quarters.

The table looks like this , however the accounts column cannot be seen. so there should be an acccount column next to actvities. it either for the program,projet or activities .

[image]

Comment: Sorry, can you add some scheme, wireframe or diagram? I don't understand what you're asking here.

Comment: This is very difficult to visualise. Can you show us what you have already and tell us what's wrong with it?